# How to find matching difference between two df

Tags: python, pandas

Looking to find the percentage difference between two dataframes. I have tried using fuzzywuzzy but not getting the expected output for the same.

Suppose i have 2 dataframes with 4 columns each, i want to find the match percentage between these 2 dataframes.

Befor execution of the code found dtypes = float64, So i have changed the dtypes = object
While Executing the code i am getting Error **TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()**

**df1**

```
score   id_number       company_name      company_code   Amount
200      IN2231D           AXN pvt Ltd        IN225      2566.7           
450      UK654IN        Aviva Intl Ltd        IN115      3677           
650.8    SL1432H   Ship Incorporations        CZ555      NaN            
350      LK0678G  Oppo Mobiles pvt ltd        PQ795      367.9           
590      NG5678J             Nokia Inc        RS885      867           
250      IN2231D           AXN pvt Ltd        IN215      785.65
```

**df2**

```
QR_score     Identity_No       comp_name      comp_code     amt           match_acc   
    200.00      IN2231D           AXN pvt Inc        IN225    2566.70             
    420.0       UK655IN        Aviva Intl Ltd        IN315    3677.00             
    350.35      SL2252H              Ship Inc        CK555    NaN              
    450.00      LK9978G  Oppo Mobiles pvt ltd        PRS95    367.9             
    590.15      NG5678J             Nokia Inc        RS885    867             
    250.0       IN5531D           AXN pvt Ltd        IN215    785.65
```

When checking for the dtypes df2['QR_score'] and df2['amt'] has the dtype float64 so i have changed the same to Object

**Code i am trying**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

df2 = df2[['QR_score','amt']].astype(str)
# Make Column Names Match
df1.columns = df2.columns
# Select string (object) columns
t1 = df1.select_dtypes(include='object')
t2 = df2.select_dtypes(include='object')
# Apply fuzz.ratio to every cell of both frames
obj_similarity = pd.DataFrame(np.vectorize(fuzz.ratio)(t1, t2), 
                              columns=t1.columns,
                              index=t1.index)
# Use non-object similarity with eq
other_similarity = df1.select_dtypes(exclude='object').eq(
    df2.select_dtypes(exclude='object')) * 100
# Merge Similarities together and take the average per row
total_similarity = pd.concat((
    obj_similarity, other_similarity
), axis=1).mean(axis=1)

df2['match_acc'] = total_similarity
```

> While executing the below line getting the error :

```
obj_similarity = pd.DataFrame(np.vectorize(fuzz.ratio)(t1, t2), 
                              columns=t1.columns,
                              index=t1.index)

Error:TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Please Suggest.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue on my end. Consider putting actual _code constructors_ for each DataFrame instead of plaintext to ensure that the values are exactly as they appear on your end. Something like `df1.head().to_dict()` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stack` both the dataframes `concat` them and `apply` `fuzz` (axis = 1). Then to restructure use `unstack` and finally take the `mean`(axis = 1).

```
df2['match_acc'] = pd.concat([df1.stack(), df2.stack()], 1).apply(
    lambda x: fuzz.ratio(str(x[0]), str(x[1])), 1).unstack().mean(1)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
   QR_score Identity_No             comp_name comp_code      amt  match_acc
0    200.00     IN2231D           AXN pvt Inc     IN225  2566.70      94.60
1    420.00     UK655IN        Aviva Intl Ltd     IN315  3677.00      89.20
2    350.35     SL2252H              Ship Inc     CK555      NaN      62.75
3    450.00     LK9978G  Oppo Mobiles pvt ltd     PRS95   367.90      82.20
4    590.15     NG5678J             Nokia Inc     RS885   867.00      94.60
5    250.00     IN5531D           AXN pvt Ltd     IN215   785.65      94.20
```